# filtering a collection using Linq - how to reuse the same filter

Tags: c#, linq

I am filtering a collection and I perform 2 filters that are the same but for different fields.
There must be a way I can reduce the duplication of code here?
The checks are whether a date has been entered, and whether it is before a cut off date entered by the user.

```
    public override IList<Company> Search()
    {
        var list = CacheObjects.Subcontractors;

        this.ApplicationFormReturnedCheck(ref list);

        this.ApplicationFormSentCheck(ref list);
    }

    private void ApplicationFormReturnedCheck(ref IList<Subcontractor> list)
    {
        if (this.ApplicationFormNotReturnedFlag == true && this.ApplicationFormReturned != null)
        {
            list =
                list.Where(x => x.ApplicationFormReturned == null || x.ApplicationFormReturned < this.ApplicationFormReturned).ToList();
        }
        else if (this.ApplicationFormNotReturnedFlag == true)
        {
            list = list.Where(x => x.ApplicationFormReturned == null).ToList();
        }
        else if (this.ApplicationFormReturned != null)
        {
            list = list.Where(x => x.ApplicationFormReturned < this.ApplicationFormReturned).ToList();
        }
    }

    private void ApplicationFormSentCheck(ref IList<Subcontractor> list)
    {
        if (this.ApplicationFormNotSentFlag == true && this.ApplicationFormSent != null)
        {
            list =
                list.Where(x => x.ApplicationFormSent == null || x.ApplicationFormSent < this.ApplicationFormSent).ToList();
        }
        else if (this.ApplicationFormNotSentFlag == true)
        {
            list = list.Where(x => x.ApplicationFormSent == null).ToList();
        }
        else if (this.ApplicationFormSent != null)
        {
            list = list.Where(x => x.ApplicationFormSent < this.ApplicationFormSent).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could use a Predicate Builder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305438/where-predicates-in-linq

Comment: Func. Func. Func. Did I mention Func?

Comment: is this Linq-to-SQL or just plain ol' LINQ on a list of in-memory objects?

Comment: In memory objects. predicate builder looks like a good solution, I just need to figure it out.

Comment: I honestly see no reason to get any more complex than a `Func` as has already been suggested in the comments.

Comment: The complexity in this problem is polymorphing over the two named fields.  The exact same code is executed with the exception of the field that is being evaluated.

Comment: My answer (as well as Jamiec's) will work if the logic were the same in the two methods. However, it appears we both made the mistake of misreading the two sample methods posted, re: the variable names are very similar in naming, but are indeed different. I'll leave my answer up, but it doesn't solve the posted scenario. Good catch, @NormanH.

Comment: Oh, I spotted that, and I realised that there is no real re-use, (except within the method itself). Hence why my answer just uses locally-declared Func's rather than in a scope which could be shared between both.

Comment: I agree it would have been better if I had changed the fieldnames to make it easier to follow what is going on. That said I find the discussion here very interesting. I will be back at work tomorrow so I look forward to seeing the state of play then. I get the impression that maybe I should leave the code as it is, which surprises me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you can do something as simple as have some instances of `Func<Subcontractor,bool>` which cover your various scenarios. This is the type of `Func` that the `Where` method expects

To demonstrate let me take one of your methods and show you how:

```
private void ApplicationFormReturnedCheck(ref IList<Subcontractor> list)
{
    var isFormReturned = new Func<Subcontractor,bool>(
          x => x.ApplicationFormReturned != null);
    var isBeforeDate = new Func<Subcontractor,bool>(
          x => x.ApplicationFormReturned < this.ApplicationFormReturned);
    var isFormReturnedOrBeforeDate= new Func<Subcontractor,bool>(
          x => isFormReturned(x) || isFormReturnedBeforeDate(x));

    if (this.ApplicationFormNotReturnedFlag == true && this.ApplicationFormReturned != null)
    {
        list = list.Where(isFormReturnedOrBeforeDate).ToList();
    }
    else if (this.ApplicationFormNotReturnedFlag == true)
    {
        list = list.Where(isFormReturned).ToList();
    }
    else if (this.ApplicationFormReturned != null)
    {
        list = list.Where(isBeforeDate).ToList();
    }
}
```

The other method you've shown, although having *similar* logic, uses a different set of variables. (`ApplicationFormSent` in place of `ApplicationFormReturned`). The way I see it you have two options

1. Duplicate the above within the other method, using the differing variable names
2. Use a more complex method whereby you have these 3 `Func`'s outside of the scope of each method, and able to distinguish which variables (`*Sent` or `*Returned`) to use.

The problem with 2. above is that as your perceved "reuse" goes up, the readability of your code goes down.

In all honesty, I see no major problem with your *original code*! Its clear, its pretty concise and its easy to see what it's doing. By wrapping all this logic up with predicates (which could conceivably be elsewhere in the class), you're making it harder to read and harder to maintain.

Comment: Thank you for that. I think your code is good to use but I can see that is I had many more variations that it could get out of hand.

Answer (score 0):

A [Func(T, TResult)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) can be used to encapsulate common predicate methods. In your case, the Func would need to be initilialized in the constructor since you are using instance members in the filter. Ex:

```
private readonly Func<Subcontractor, bool> _pred;

public Subcontractor()
{
    _pred = x => x.ApplicationFormReturned == null || x.ApplicationFormReturned < this.ApplicationFormReturned;
}

private void ApplicationFormReturnedCheck( ref IList<Subcontractor> list )
{
    if( this.ApplicationFormNotReturnedFlag == true && this.ApplicationFormReturned != null )
    {
        list = list.Where( _pred ).ToList();
    }
    else if( this.ApplicationFormNotReturnedFlag == true )
    {
        list = list.Where( x => x.ApplicationFormReturned == null ).ToList();
    }
    else if( this.ApplicationFormReturned != null )
    {
        list = list.Where( x => x.ApplicationFormReturned < this.ApplicationFormReturned ).ToList();
    }
}
```